# Numpy searchsorted descending order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to understand how to correctly use numpy.searchsorted to find the correct index where to insert an element. When i run the following:

```
e = np.array([9,8,7,6])
np.searchsorted(e,5)
```

The output I get is 0, which is wrong as I would expect 4 as the answer. Is searchsorted usable for arrays ordered in descending order? What options do I have if I need to keep the array in descending order? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can search the reversed array, and then reverse the index later:

```
e = np.array([9,8,7,6])
e.size - np.searchsorted(e[::-1], 5, side = "right")
# 4
```

Notice the `side` parameter here needs to be opposite to directly search the original array if you want the result to be consistent.

Comment: This is, more or less, the solution I was thinking about, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

As is described in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

> **`numpy.searchsorted(a, v, side='left', sorter=None)`**
>
> Find indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order.
>
> Find the indices into a sorted array a such that, if the corresponding
>   elements in `v` were inserted before the indices, the order of a would
>   be preserved.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `a` : 1-D array_like
>
>   Input array. If `sorter` is `None`, then it must be **sorted in ascending order**, otherwise sorter must be an array of indices that
>     sort it.
>
> (...)

(formatting added)

So you have to provide an array sorted in *ascending* order.

Nevertheless it is easy to solve this issue **for numerical data**: you simply use the *negation*:

```
e = np.array([9,8,7,6])
np.searchsorted(-e,-5)
#               ^  ^
```

You can also use the reversed array (for instance for non-numerical data) as is proposed by [@Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43095889/67579).

Comment: multiplying the array by -1 ! Does that not make the O(logn) algo O(n)?

Comment: That's a great insight. You should be named Willem Van Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the `sorter` optional argument.  As per the documentation this is usually the result of `np.argsort(e)`:

```
array([3, 2, 1, 0])
```

Which you can produce more efficiently this way:

```
np.arange(len(e)-1, -1, -1)
```

Then:

```
np.searchsorted(e, 7.5, sorter=np.arange(len(e)-1, -1, -1))
```

Gives you 2.